PDFs with ReportLab in Django. Punjabi Unicode (e.g., ਵਿਰੋਧ ਦੇ ਸਮੇਂ ਫਾਸ਼ੀਵਾਦ) is not displaying correctly. Need font solution
def generate_punjabi_pdf(request):
    font_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/myapp/css/fonts/Noto_Sans_Gurmukhi/static', 'NotoSansGurmukhi-Regular.ttf')

    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('NotoSansGurmukhi', font_path))

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="punjabi_text.pdf"'
    c = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=A4)

    c.setFont("NotoSansGurmukhi", 16)

    c.drawString(100, 750, "ਵਿਰੋਧ ਦੇ ਸਮੇਂ ਫਾਸ਼ੀਵਾਦ")

    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    return response

I've tried using different libraries like fpdf2, but the Sihari of the Punjabi text is misplaced, showing shifted to the next character.

What do you exactly mean with "showing shifted to the next character."?

Please [edit] your question to include the information you mistakenly put in an answer.
